# Symfony multiple file uploading resets previous fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, event-listener

Or otherwise, question is how to not update existing fields, if FileTypes are empty.

I used [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/controller/upload_file.html) for making file uploading in two fields (Eaudit and Tspec) in entity Household, using Doctrine Listener.
Only I didn't use Uploader Service as in example, upload() exist in the same class, and field file storing directories paths passed as service arguments.

Problem is if I submit again the form, it clears previous field data
(e.g. I already submitted the Eaudit, after page reload trying to submit Tspecification, and notice that Eaudit is null, and otherwise).

Despite on postLoad(), Form is showing empty FileTypes. Also I use eauditName/tspecificationName fields for storing UploadedFile original names.

**EDIT:**
Noticed that if remove fields, which contains data with

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
    $household = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    if (null !== $household->getEaudit()) {
        $form->remove('eaudit');
    }
    if (null !== $household->getTspecification()) {
        $form->remove('tspecification');
    }
});
```

Form doesn't show form_rest(), and after submit it all the same field with data updates in DB, but with my real path, e.g. C:\Users\Admin\file.doc.

Symfony 2.8.19, Please help in my problem, thank you for your attention.

```
class DocumentsUploadListener {
    private $eaudit;
    private $tspec;

    public function __construct($eaudit, $tspec) {
        $this->eaudit = $eaudit;
        $this->tspec = $tspec;
    }

    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $this->uploadFile($entity);
    }

    private function uploadFile($entity) {
        if (!$entity instanceof Household) {
            return;
        }
        $file1 = $entity->getEaudit();
        // only upload new files
        if ($file1 instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $fileName1 = $this->upload($this->eaudit, $file1);
            $entity->setEaudit($fileName1);
            $entity->setEauditName($file1->getClientOriginalName());
        }

        $file2 = $entity->getTspecification();
        if ($file2 instanceof UploadedFile) {
            $fileName2 = $this->upload($this->tspec, $file2);
            $entity->setTspecification($fileName2);
            $entity->setTspecificationName($file2->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if (!$entity instanceof Household) {
            return;
        }
        if ($fileName1 = $entity->getEaudit()) {
            $entity->setEaudit(new File($this->eaudit.'/'.$fileName1));
        }

        if ($fileName2 = $entity->getTspecification()) {
            $entity->setTspecification(new File($this->tspec.'/'.$fileName2));
        }
    }

    public function upload($dest, UploadedFile $file) {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move($dest, $fileName);
        return $fileName;
    }
}
```

Form class:

```
class HouseholdDocumentsType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('eaudit', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('tspecification', FileType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => Household::class
            ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'app_bundle_household_documents_type';
    }
}
```

Entity class:

```
/**
 * Household
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="households")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\HouseholdRepository")
 */
class Household {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"})
     */
    protected $eaudit;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $eauditName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={"application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"})
     */
    protected $tspecification;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $tspecificationName;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEaudit() {
        return $this->eaudit;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $eaudit
     */
    public function setEaudit($eaudit) {
        $this->eaudit = $eaudit;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $tspecification
     * @return Household
     */
    public function setTspecification($tspecification) {
        $this->tspecification = $tspecification;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTspecification() {
        return $this->tspecification;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $eauditName
     * @return Household
     */
    public function setEauditName($eauditName) {
        $this->eauditName = $eauditName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEauditName() {
        return $this->eauditName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $tspecificationName
     * @return Household
     */
    public function setTspecificationName($tspecificationName) {
        $this->tspecificationName = $tspecificationName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTspecificationName() {
        return $this->tspecificationName;
    }
}
```